# Content delivery design

Tags: design, architecture, http

I'm designing a system where users can access files stored in an external content storage service such as AWS's S3. Here's a simple diagram:

```
 ------       ------------       -----------------
| User | <=> | Web Server | <=> | Content Storage |
 ------       ------------       -----------------
```

The files are stored with a (long) unique ID. I'm concerned mainly about two things: performance and information security.

There are two options that come to mind but I'm sure it can be done in a better way (performance and security-wise):

1. Give the user a url with which the file can be downloaded directly from the content storage service. Cons: the URL could be brute forced. This could be solved putting a password to the file, but I'd like to use that as a last resort.
2. The web server downloads the file from content storage service and then serves it to the user. Cons: too much traffic.

Is there a way to make an HTTP redirect without exposing the file's resolved URL? Something like proxying packets?

I don't want to make this technology-specific (that's what SO is for), but just in case it adds any value, I'm using Rails a rails server behind nginx. I have full control over the web server, but I'm limited on the content storage service since I'm using S3.

Comment: If files are stored with long unique IDs, which I guess are parts of file URLs, how could they be brute forced?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see now is to use [REST authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) provided by Amazon

It creates expiring URLs that can be given to third-party. So, basically the idea is to login user to your website, check his permissions and then generate URL for him to download file from.

[AWS IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/aws/aws-iam-now-supports-amazon-facebook-and-google-identity-federation/) also can be used for that, but that limits the number of options, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you already suggested this with "password to the file": combine option 1 (url to download directly) with encryption of the file, so that it can be securely decrypted by the client application only by clients with possession of a secret key. That is probably a minimum level of security anyway, if you are concerned about security at all. It won't help with denial of service attacks.